# Spatial functions in HIVE

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, geospatial, spatial

We are in the process of migrating from traditional RDMS technologies to HIVE and in the process we have few questions on  HIVE spatial capabilties.  1) Mapping of operation dbo.fHTMToString spatial  from sql server operation to  HIVE 2) Mapping of operation dbo.FHtmToLatLon spatial  from sql server operation  in HIVE

Answer (score 0):

Spatial functions are not available yet in Hive. There are a proposal document you can find here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Spatial+queries

Answer (score 0):

Try the Esri [Spatial Framework for Hadoop](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop), which includes an implementation of ST_Geometry for Hive.

You can start with the [sample for Hive](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/tree/master/samples/point-in-polygon-aggregation-hive) in the [GIS Tools for Hadoop](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/) repository.

There are example calls to the various ST_Geometry UDFs in the scripts under [spatial-framework-for-hadoop/hive/test/](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/tree/master/hive/test).

(Disclosure: I'm a collaborator.)

Comment: Thanks we migrated to spark and most of the things are available there with geospark